# Guest user showing in customer list Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento 1.9, i checkout as a guest and after place order that guest user is logged-in. Also have entry in admin customer list.
Please anybody can tell me how can i solve this.
Thank you

Comment: Please check there must be some custom module which is converting guests to customer.

Comment: @Mohit, Thank you for your quick reply. But i checked module is not issue. Please can you guess what may be ?

Comment: any body please can help me into this

Comment: no anyone have any idea about it ?

Comment: Guys, I have solved it my self...

Comment: Please share your solution so that others can take benefit from your findings.